# using fullText or mimeType query to search files in google drive v3 api gives "Invalid Value" message

Tags: .net, google-drive-api, full-text-search, mime-types

Currently I want to search files in google drive using Google.Apis.Drive.v3 package in .net framework. But When I fill the Files.List().Q with `(fullText contains 'pdf') or (mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document')`, it will throw a GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Invalid Value [400] Errors [Message[Invalid Value] Location[q - parameter] Reason[invalid] Domain[global]].

The code snippet is:

```cs
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = credential });
var listRequest = service.Files.List();
listRequest.Q = "(fullText contains 'pdf') or (mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document')";
var fileList = listRequest.Execute();
```

I have also tried the API in [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)(in the right `Try this API` pannel).

When I fill `q` parameter with `(fullText contains 'pdf') or (mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document')` and then click `Execute` button. It gives the same error message.

But when I replace `or` with `and` in the query: `(fullText contains 'pdf') and (mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document')` and click `Execute` again, it just succeeds, no errors!.

It seems when combining `fullText` field with `mimeType` field using `or` operator, this issue will come out.

It's really strange behavior. Maybe a bug of google api. [Here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/issues/382) is a related issue in github.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Can you add any details like code used? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @jess I have add the code snippet in c#. Actually you can just go `Try this API` in the above link to test.